# NullPointerException on cassandra ThriftServer stop

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, cassandra

I'm using cassandra to store data on my application. Everything goes fine until I try to stop it. When stopping, sometimes I reveice a NullPointerException as follows:

```
15:58:56.869 ERROR [Thread-2] [CassandraDaemon.java:185] Exception in thread Thread[Thread-2,5,main]
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.ThriftServer.stop(ThriftServer.java:70) [cassandra-all-2.2.6-E001.jar:2.2.6-E001]
at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.stop(CassandraDaemon.java:452) [cassandra-all-2.2.6-E001.jar:2.2.6-E001]
at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.deactivate(CassandraDaemon.java:564) [cassandra-all-2.2.6-E001.jar:2.2.6-E001]
at mypackage.CassandraDaemonForTest$1.run(CassandraDaemonForTest.java:96) [testutils-6.3.0.jar:na]
```

According to the class source, this is the point where the problem happens:

```
public void stop()
{
    if (server != null)
    {
        server.stopServer();
        try
        {
            server.join();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            logger.error("Interrupted while waiting thrift server to stop", e);
        }
        server = null;
    }
}
```

Apparrently, there are several instances of the same ThriftServer running, and when I try to deactivate, some pass the null check and causes the problem when calling the next method on the instance. My debugger show at least three calls to this method on the same instance:

[image: method callstack]

Any suggest of how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was reported and fixed in [CASSANDRA-12105](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-12105), for versions 2.2.8, 3.0.9, 3.8, and above. If multiple threads called `stop` at the same time, then one could set `server` to `null` after the other thread has checked for

```
server != null
```

and then throw a `NullPointerException` on the following invocations

```
server.stopServer(); 
// or
server.join();
```

The [method was made `synchronized`](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/commit/9a8406f2f7f03fb1794e6cb0b5585579cb93cc92) for an isolated check and invocation.

Consider upgrading.